# drupal 6 jquery module additions

Tags: jquery, authentication, module, drupal-6

this is what the module has in it now for basic toggle of the login box.

```
   Drupal.logintoboggan_toggleboggan = function() {
  $("#toboggan-login-link").click(
    function () {
      $("#toboggan-login").slideToggle("fast");
      this.blur();
      return false;
    }
  );
};
```

this is what i have the works for what i need it to inside the module. i just want to move it outside without modifiying the module itself.

```
Drupal.logintoboggan_toggleboggan = function() {
  $("#toboggan-login-link").click(
    function () {
      $("#toboggan-login").slideToggle("slow", function() {
         if($(this).css('display') == 'block'){
                 $("#art-main").append('<div class="outer-login"></div>');
                     $(".outer-login").click( function () {
                          $("#toboggan-login").slideToggle("fast");
                          $(this).remove();
                     });
      } else{
          $(".outer-login").remove();
      }
      });


      this.blur();
      return false;
    }
  );
```

i have tried using unset to remove the loggintoboggan.js file but with jquery update module installed that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom module that has a higher weight than the `loggintoboggan` module. This module adds a JS file where it overwrites the JS function you're interested in. The key is making sure that your custom JS file is loaded after `loggintoboggan` has had the change to load it's JS files.

This is how your `.install` file would look like. It makes sure, your module is called after `loggintoboggan`

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_enable
* @file your_module_name.install
* @see http://drupal.org/node/110238 (http://drupal.org/node/110238)
*/
function your_module_name_enable {
    // Find out the weight of the logintoboggan module
    $weight = db_result(db_query("SELECT weight FROM {system} WHERE name = '[logintoboggan]'"));

    // Set our module to a weight 1 higher
    db_query("UPDATE {system} SET weight = %d WHERE name = '[your_module_name]'", $weight + 1);
}
```

Your `.module` file is very simple, just adds a JS file.

```
/**
* @file your_module_name.module
* @see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_init/6
*/
function your_module_name_init() {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'your_module_name') . '/your_module_name.js');
}
```

In your `.js` file make sure to add the overwritten function. I'm not a JS guru but it should be along these lines.

```
// Make a backup, maybe we'll need the original implementation
var orig_logintoboggan_toggleboggan = Drupal.logintoboggan_toggleboggan;

// Overwrite the function
Drupal.logintoboggan_toggleboggan = function() {
  // ... new implementation ...
};
```

So you're custom module should have the following structure:

```
cd your_module_name/
.. your_module_name.install
.. your_module_name.module
.. your_module_name.js
```

Clear the Drupal cache and the browser cache to make sure all the JS files are loaded correctly.

Comment: i tried this setup and check to make sure the custom module js file is loaded before logintoboggan.js but that does not trump the toboggan js file it is still being read first regardless. i even went to so far as to add function js_alter and unset logintoboggan.js in the module but that also does not work.

Comment: your js file should be loaded **after** the `logintoboggan.js` file, not _before_. this is very important. The last function declaration will be used. So when you view the source it should be like this: `logintoboggan.js` and then `your_module_name.js`

Comment: the js file for the module where the changes where placed is loading first before any other js file.

Comment: @PH83, that is precisely the reason Max states in his answer, in the very first sentence: "_Create a custom module that has a **higher weight** than the loggintoboggan module._"

Comment: @kekkis my issue is that i cannot check to make sure the db query is actually adding weight onto my module to work properly and i think that may be the issue. i unfortunately was not given db access.

Comment: alright, tried multiple different ways to do the db update and installed a module that allowed me to change weight in backend and still the no difference and what order it reads the js file. Thanks for the help @max but i dont think this theory will work.

Comment: PH83, do you have access to the database? Then run this query and paste the results: `select name, weight from system where name like '%logintoboggan%' or name like '%your_module_name%';`. And of course replace `your_module_name` with the name of the custom module you created. As long as the `JS` file with the changes is loaded first of course it's not going to work.

Comment: @Max nope, no access to database at all. Long story short my current contractor doesnt believe a front-end developer needs access to the database. The do not seem to mind the wat its setup at this time so i will leave it that way.

Comment: Well, if you can enable modules, then you basically have access to the database. Just use `db_query` to run it and fetch the results. hope you find a solution to your problem.